# sortedArrayUsingComparator not working for array in IOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

hello i want to sort the array with oldest to latest date. it works perfect for the small data. but when the data is large not getting the perfect soreted array.

here is my code

```
  -(NSMutableArray *)sortArrayOldestTonewest:(NSMutableArray *)arr{

    NSArray *sortedArray;

    NSMutableArray *arrResponse=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arr];

    sortedArray = [arrResponse sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a,id b) {
        NSString *str1 = [a valueForKey:@"CardExpiryDate"];
        NSString *str2 = [b valueForKey:@"CardExpiryDate"];

        NSDate *date1=[Utility dateFromString:str1 withFormat:@"dd/mm/yyyy"];
        NSDate *date2=[Utility dateFromString:str2 withFormat:@"dd/mm/yyyy"];

        return [date1 compare:date2];

    }];

    NSMutableArray  *arrResult=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:sortedArray];
    return arrResult
    ;

}
```

what i am doing wrong.
please help.

Comment: Can you specify what *large* data is? Can you provide the data, and are you sure that it's correct?

Comment: @Sunny str1 and str2 hold the same card expiry date string  coz you are using the same dictionary object a to get Card Expiry Date value.

Comment: large data its about the more than 1500 array(contains dictionary object) count. @NSAddict i am not sure ite perfect or not.

Comment: "trivial syntax error" category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date format is wrong, it should be `@"dd/MM/yyyy"`.

"MM" is for month, "mm" is for minutes.
It must be pure coincidence that your results were correct for small datasets.